# User mode install of TeXLive on a Mac

Tags: installing, mac

My university decided to not give admin privileges automatically. So I thought I will try installing it in user mode on the university provided Mac (Mojave). I installed TexLive 2019 (option -gui -text) with two changes: root directory is ~/texlive and TEXMFHOME is ~/texmf. I left TEXMFVAR and TEXMFCONFIG in ~/Library/texlive default. I also added the appropriate line to .bashrc (sourced from .bash-profile) to fix up the path.

Now when I try to tex a file I get the following error message:
=>> lstat(./pdftex) failed: ./pdftex: No such file or directory
=>> kpathsea: Can't get directory of program name: ./pdftex
Path is set correctly: texlua --help produces the expected output

The error message makes sense to me only if kpathsea thinks that it has successfully cd'ed to the directory containing the binary of the program being invoked, but it has not. That means that it is a simple permissions issue. All directories involved show "drwxr-xr-x" and no "+" or "@" at the end. That is the extent of my knowledge of permissions. So I can't figure out what is going on.

Addendum: Following a suggestion elsewhere I tried a portable installation. It has the same problem. I have also tried putting texmf-var and texmf-config in a directory in home, rather than in ~/Library. This also makes no difference. I tried creating symlinks to ~/bin etc, and put ~/bin in the path. No dice.

Finally, "which" will not show the commands in directories I add to path. So texlua --help produces the expected output, but which texlua does nothing.

Comment: exactly how are you running pdftex? From an editor or from the command line (terminal)? Try the latter, you might not have set the PATHs such that an editor can use them

Comment: I am running pdftex from Terminal (bash). I am sure that I have the PATH set right: otherwise, I would not expect texlua to run, nor would I expect the error message to come from kpathsea. [If the path is not set right, shouldn't the error message be "command not found"?]

Comment: Might be because texlua does not read the same config as the rest. I would not have split things up like this. I would run the text based installer, change only texdir, letting the installer adjust it self, and install there.

Comment: Well, in my first attempt, I left TEXMFCONFIG in its default location (~/Library/texlive/...) In every one of my attempts, texmf.cnf had the expected entries. [According to comments in it, it all depends on SELFAUTOLOC being set up. It looks like that is supposed to be set up on the fly, but that is not happening.]

Comment: Normally when you install TeLive by hand, it has a single root (on Linux I have it in /opt/texlive/year/), then all configurations sits below this single root, and self auto works. When you spread it out like this, then you really need to know that texmf.cnf is configured correctly.

Comment: I'm also wondering, where does this come from: `lstat(./pdftex)`, normally when you run `pdftex` from the command line on a Mac I would not expect to see `lstat`, how exactly are you testing this?

Comment: The easy question (from daleif) first: According to kpathsea documentation, kpathsea sets SELFAUTOLOC first and then uses texmf.cnf to set other environment variables. It also sas that the magic happens in progname.c. progname.c has a line where it calls lstat. I do not feel qualified to dig deeper into the code to see where the ./pdftex (or whatever program I invoke, the same thing happens with luatex, kpsewhich, etc) comes from.

Comment: Regarding the texmf tree: The tree is set up exactly the way it would in user mode install in Linux (or could be in Windows, I have checked that it works there too): Main distribution tree in ~/texlive/2019, local additions ins ~/texlive/texmf-local, and personal tree in ~/tesmf. I cannot put links in /usr etc due to lack of admin access. It is no more (or less) spead out than the usual MacTeX setup except that nothing is in system directories.

Comment: I don't know why I did not test this earlier: Running the programs by giving the full path (/Users/ etc) works.